# delta is not defined in the class

Tags: python, django

```
class timetravel(object):
    """
    Fast forward in time with simulated CRON jobs (used for unit testing)
    """
    delta = None

def __init__(self, *args):
    self.initial_now = datetime.now()
    if isinstance(args[0], timedelta):
        self.delta = delta
    elif isinstance(args[0], datetime):
        self.now = args[0]
        if args[0] > self.initial_now:
            self.delta = args[0] - self.initial_now
        else:
            self.delta = self.initial_now - args[0]
    else:
        print("Please provide a datetime or timedelta object as argument")
   #self.now = self.initial_now
   #self.freezer = freeze_time(self.now)
   #self.freezer.start()

def __enter__(self):
    # Traveling in the past, we don't run cron jobs backward
    if self.now < self.initial_now:
        self.now = self.now - self.delta
        self.freezer = freeze_time(self.now)
        self.freezer.start()
    # Traveling in the future, run cron jobs
    else:
        self.now = self.initial_now
        self.freezer = freeze_time(self.now)
        self.freezer.start()
        hours   = self.delta.total_seconds() / 60 / 60
        weekday = self.now.weekday()
        month   = self.now.month
        year    = self.now.year
        for i in range(1, int(hours)+1):
            call_command('cron', hourly=True, verbosity=0)
            if weekday != self.now.weekday():
                weekday = self.now.weekday()
                call_command('cron', daily=True)
            if self.now.weekday() == 6 and weekday != self.now.weekday():
                call_command('cron', weekly=True)
            if self.now.month != month:
                month = self.now.month
                call_command('cron', monthly=True)
            if self.now.year != year:
                year = self.now.year
                call_command('cron', yearly=True)
            self.freezer.stop()
            self.now = self.now + timedelta(hours=1)
            self.freezer = freeze_time(self.now)
            self.freezer.start()
    return self.now

def __exit__(self, *args):
    self.freezer.stop()
```

If I create a function

```
 def function(self):

        with timetravel(datetime(2017,03,01)) as now:
        ...
```

when I run `python manage.py test`, I obtain

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 42, in test_timetravel
    with timetravel(datetime.timedelta(days=2)) as now:
  File ".../utils/testing.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.delta = delta
NameError: global name 'delta' is not defined
```

I can't say why it is not working.

> 2- How could I fix this issue? In fact, as I am new in programming. So what would be a good example of what we have to insert in `timetravel` as argument?

Comment: I'm writing to you as a reviewer because this is your first question on SO. To get good results here there are some principles you need to observe. (1) Try to reduce the length of the code you submit to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the difficulty you're experiencing. (2) Read relevant documentation and look for previous answers to see if you can find answers for yourself. (You should be able to get an answer for your first question.) (3) Try to be precise about what you want your code to do. In this case, what do you want to 'pass in' and what should the result be?

Answer (score 0):

`delta` is a class attribute that can be accessed from an instance with `self.delta`. You can override this attribute `self.delta = 12`, then it becomes an instance attribute.

So in your code, you have to simply remove the lines:

```
if isinstance(args[0], timedelta):
    self.delta = delta
```